# How to simplify switch statement

Tags: go, binary, switch-statement, byte, reflect

I have a decoder function that takes a byte slice and `reflect.Kind` and returns an interface and an error. The interface will be asserted when it is used in other parts of the code. Is there a way to simplify my switch statement so I don't have to repeat the NewReader, Read, and error handling in each case?

What I have now:

```
func decoder(byteValue []byte, t reflect.Kind) (interface{}, error) {
    switch t {
    case reflect.Int16:
        var ret int16
        buf := bytes.NewReader(byteValue)
        err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &ret)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        return ret, nil
    case reflect.Int32:
        var ret int32
        buf := bytes.NewReader(byteValue)
        err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &ret)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        return ret, nil
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for:

```
func decoder(byteValue []byte, t reflect.Kind) (interface{}, error) {
    switch t {
    case reflect.Int16:
        var ret int16
    case reflect.Int32:
        var ret int32
    }
    buf := bytes.NewReader(byteValue)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &ret)
    if err != nil {
        return ret, err
    }
    return ret, nil
}
```

I know this wont work because `ret` is only defined in the scope of the switch case and is lost outside of it.

Comment: unworthy in my opinion because if you declare ret as an interface{], you got to fill it with pointer to int16/32, which later need to be dereferenced to int16/int32, thus type asserted, before it is returned.

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
var ret interface{}
switch t {
case reflect.Int16:
    var i int16
    ret = &i
case reflect.Int32:
    var i int32
    ret = &i
}
buf := bytes.NewReader(byteValue)
// NOT &ret since ret is already an interface value containing a pointer
err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, ret)
if err != nil {
    return ret, err
}
return ret, nil
```

This is always going to be a painful solution to use though, because returning `interface{}` is pretty useless - callers will always have to do assertion or type switch or reflection. What I would do in that scenario is take the value to fill instead of a `reflect.Kind` - i.e., just what `binary.Read` does:

```
func decoder(byteValue []byte, val interface{}) error {
    return binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(byteValue), binary.BigEndian, val)
}
```

Of course, that doesn't save you much repeated code, which tells you that `binary.Read` is already a pretty clean API that doesn't really need a wrapper.

Comment: No, it was returning `interface{}`.

Comment: OK.... It was returning wrapped int16/int32 within interface, you are returning wrapped pointers to int16/int32.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: I like the second approach. Makes me a little sad I didn't think of that. Thanks a ton.